# Как убить IntentService

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

Для примера я создал сервис с таймером. Туда передаю какие-то параметры для сверки. Через какое-то время я опять запускаю `startService`, но с новыми параметрами. В таком случае старый сервис нужно убить. `stopService` как я понял не поможет, `onHandleIntent` так и останется работать. Может быть можно как-то обновить параметры в старом сервисе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntentService` получаемые параметры обрабатывает по очереди, то есть если вы сначала запустили `startService()` с одними параметрами, потом еще раз, но с другими параметрами, то будет 1 сервис, который будет обрабатывать запросы по очереди и они (разные запросы) не будут "мешать" друг другу.

Так что "убивать" нет необходимости.

Comment: Этот сервис взаимодействует с сервером. Т.е. если я запущу 10 таких сервисов и каждый будет отправлять на сервер запросы, это не есть хорошо.

Comment: Т.е. мне нужно как-то прекратить первый запрос и запустить второй

Comment: Эммм... то есть ты выстрелил одну стрелу, потом стреляешь вслед вторую стрелу и тут подумал - млин первую стрелу я зря выстрелил, надо вернуть ее обратно :) Это так не работает...

Comment: Доходчивый пример) А как мне тогда такое реализовать? Мне нужно отправлять каждые `n` минут данные на сервер. `n` передается в сервис как параметр.

Comment: Вся суть в том, что `n` время от времени меняется

Comment: Вы спрашиваете как вернуть пущенную стрелу? Хмм... даже не знаю. Расскажите подробнее саму бизнес задачу (лучше отдельным вопросом со ссылкой на данный вопрос)